# Newsletters not sending

Tags: newsletter

I'm queuing newsletters but they are not getting sent.
Any ideas where to start?
The configuration are correct, people can sign up/off, but nothing gets sent.
Thanks

Comment: is youre cron running?

Answer (score 4):

1. Check if Magento cron is running by looking into `cron_schedule` table. There should be resent records for newsletter queue listed in the table and status of the module execution
2. Run cron service manually by pointing your browser to http://your.magento.url.here/cron.php
3. Enable PHP mail log:
   http://php.net/manual/en/mail.configuration.php#ini.mail.log
4. Check outgoing mail queue on server with `mailq` command
5. Try to send all mail via external mail server by installing one of SMTP extensions:  http://www.magentocommerce.com/magento-connect/smtp-pro-email-free-custom-smtp-email.html
6. Ensure that newsletter messages are not ending up in Spam folders.

Comment: Thank you for the answer.
I was hoping for something a lot less technical :/

Comment: On running cron.php and checking apache logs, I found sendmail was not installed on server. After installing it worked. Thanks a lot.

Comment: Does it require to install Sendmail or it will work with SMTP as well?